# Getting a file pointer from file descriptor

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-5.2

In PHP 5.2.3, "fdopen" was used to read/write to a file descriptor that's opened by another application.

```
fdopen(<fileDescriptorId>,"rw");  //It worked fine with PHP 5.2.3
```

After upgrading PHP to 5.3.2, it's throwing "`undefined reference to 'fdopen' function`".

Please suggest whats the replacement for this in PHP 5.3.2 or any workaround.

Comment: FYI, as of PHP/5.3.6, the `php://fd` wrapper [is supported](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php).

Answer (score 3):

As of PHP 5.3.6 (and still valid and working with PHP 7.2.1), the proper method to access a file descriptor is to use `fopen` with [php://fd](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php#wrappers.php.fd):

```
$fd = 3;
$pipe = fopen("php://fd/{$fd}", 'w');
fwrite($pipe, 'hello!');
```

Answer (score 2):

Could this fdopen() of yours have been provided by a custom php extension?
On a linux/unix server

```
function fdopen($id, $mode) {
  return fopen("/proc/self/fd/".(int)$id, $mode);
}
```

*might* work.

edit: see http://linux.die.net/man/5/proc

Comment: Thanks. PHP-cgi binary is invoked by a webserver that runs in a jail directory(sandbox).So,it doesn't have access to the file (socket) path ("/proc/self/fd/" . (int)$id,$mode) directly.
Is there any way in PHP to read/write given only file descriptor number [assuming if the file path is not known as its not accessible in this case].
Please let me know your comments.

Answer (score 0):

The `fdopen` is related to **C language**. There is no such function in PHP. I think you have mis-typed the PHP's [`fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) function, right?

Comment: Yes,I also searched for "fdopen" in PHP 5.2.3 API but couldn't find this.
But it didn't report any error with PHP 5.2.3 [double-checked it and didn't mistype] might be as VolkerK suggested some other extension might have been built with that version.